# Scrape and return a value from within a div class with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Any idea how can i retrieve the price (now 2917.99) from this source code view-https://www.emag.ro/televizor-led-smart-samsung-138-cm-55ru7402-4k-ultra-hd-ue55ru7402uxxh/pd/DTN2XZBBM/

If I call the class p.product-new-price i get None.

I have managed to get the title, but not the price.

What I have done so far:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://www.emag.ro/televizor-led-smart-samsung-138-cm-55ru7402-4k-ultra-hd-ue55ru7402uxxh/pd/DTN2XZBBM/'

headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('title')

div = soup.find('div', {"class" : 'product-new-price'})

text = div.string

print(text)
```

The class looks like below and I want to extract the 2917 as int.

```
div class="product-highlight product-page-pricing"    
            p class="product-new-price"
       2.917<sup>99</sup> <span>Lei</span>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with minor modifications:

- It seems that the class `product-new-price` is on the `p` element for me!
- I am assuming there will always be a `<sup>` tag after the main price

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.emag.ro/televizor-led-smart-samsung-138-cm-55ru7402-4k-ultra-hd-ue55ru7402uxxh/pd/DTN2XZBBM/'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find('title')

p = soup.find('p', {"class" : 'product-new-price'})

# Get the text before <sup> tag
value = p.find('sup').previousSibling.strip()
print("Value: {}".format(value))

# Keep only numbers
value = ''.join(c for c in value if c.isdigit())
price = int(value)
print("Price: {}".format(price))
```

The above prints:

```
$ python3 ./test.py
Value: 2.917
Price: 2917
```

Now, with small changes you can also add the missing .99 if this is required

Comment: @OviSele feel free to accept it if it did the job ;)